# Frequency of Vortex Shedding

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

Suppose we have a long cylinder with diameter $D$, then we move it parallel to its axis with a velocity $V$ in a medium such that the Reynolds number of the flow is in the range $250<R_e<2\times10^5$. As a result, vortex shedding will takes place with a frequency

$f=\frac{S_tV}{D} $

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_shedding

Where $S_t$ is the *Strouhal number*

This formula looks so simple, except for the Strouhal number. So I think maybe there are some simple explanations for it.

Can anybody provide a simple model to explain at least the proportionality of the vortex shedding frequency with $V/D$? (Without using dimensional analysis of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [@Killercam is right](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/31980/520), I'll try to explain the same thing a little more elaborately.

Firstly. in the case considered, since the fluid and the cylinder is chosen, increase in velocity directly translates to increase in the Reynolds number as $R_e = \frac{\rho V D}{\mu}$.

Before considering flow in the range $250 < R_e < 2\times 10^5$ , lets first observe what happens in the region where the viscous force dominates over inertial forces i.e $R_e <<1$. The fluid slowly "crawls" over the surface of the cylinder. There are 2 stagnation points  on the leftmost and rightmost parts of the cylinder.
[image]

From the solution for inviscid flow over cylinder ([superposition](http://www.ecourses.ou.edu/cgi-bin/ebook.cgi?doc&topic=fl&chap_sec=07.4&page=theory)) we can note that tangential velocity is maximum at mid-section and decreases as and decreases as we proceed "downhill"

This can be extended to viscous flow and two important things are to be noted here:

1. The shear stress is maximum at the mid-section, which is implicit as a higher velocity gradient is created because of the larger value of tangential velocity.
2. The static pressure starts to increase after the mid-section. i.e the pressure is increasing in the direction of flow $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}>0$ which is called as an *adverse pressure gradient*

As $R_e$ is increased (i.e velocity is increased), the inertial forces start to dominate over viscous forces.The flow velocity is zero at the surface and the particles very close to the boundary have a very low momentum since they experience very strong viscous forces. On the right part of the cylinder, the fluid particles close to the cylinder not only experience strong viscous force, but also adverse pressure gradient which eventually forces the fluid particles to stop/reversed, causing the neighboring particles o move away from the surface. This is called as flow separation. It results in the creation of a free shear layer which ultimately rolls up to form a vortex.

@Killercam said:

> The velocity of the flow divided by the diameter of the cylinder is the typical crossing time of the fluid, hence is directly related to the frequency of the observed oscillations for a specific Reynolds number.

After a vortex is shed, the fluid particles behind have to undergo the same process i.e it takes the same distance to come to rest and then causing the neighboring particles to separate. Since this distance is a small part of the cylinder, $dist \propto D$ and hence the time interval between 2 vortices shed from the same side(top/bottom) of the cylinder $time \propto \frac{dist}{V}$ i.e $time \propto \frac{D}{V}$.

The time interval is exactly the time period of vortex shedding and hence the frequency of shedding is
$f=\frac{1}{T}\propto \frac{V}{D}$

Comment: Thank you, things are clearer to me now. But I need to think about it for a while..

Comment: @Emitabsorb, glad to help :) I'm yet to figure out the relation between $S_t$ and the shedding frequency $f$. Do post it here in case you figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

The velocity of the flow divided by the diameter of the cylinder is the typical crossing time of the fluid, hence is directly related to the frequency of the observed oscillations for a specific Reynolds number. It is as simple as that. Clearly, this time scale is then correlated with observation to provide the Strouhal number for this particular phenomenon.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't think it's that simple. The frequency in the formula corresponds to how fast the wake "moves" back and forth. It doesn't directly related to how fast the fluid passes through the cylinder right? It's much more complicated.
Take a look at this
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPBKR9cSce0

Comment: Of course the phenominon is more complex. You are asking how you can think about the $V/D$ componant of this simple formula - neglecting the Strouhal number. Well neglecting the Strouhal number you are also neglecting the details, as it is this dimensionless number that classifies the oscillating flow mechanism. $V/D$ here provides the flow crossing time which does have a direct bearing on the shedding frequency... I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't say that I would neglect the Strouhal number. The fact that Strouhal number is almost constant in this region is part of the question, it is one of the reason why the formula is so simple. Wait a second, what do you mean be the flow crossing time? Can you explain more clearly how does it related to how fast the wake switch from one side to the other?

Comment: The flow crossing time is the time taken for fluid to cross the dyameter of the cylinder... The faster the flow the faster the higher the frequencies which the eddies are being shed (for a constant Reynolds number, hence constant $S_{t}$ number).

Comment: There is a leap in logic here "The faster the flow the faster the higher the frequencies which the eddies are being shed". Suppose at a moment, the flow is building a vortex in one direction and then after a while it starts creating another vortex in the opposite direction. You are just talking about how fast one vortex is getting bigger. What matters here is how long does it takes to change the direction of the wake, am I right?

Comment: (Sorry there was a miss print above). You are right. Look at the formula for constant Re. It is telling you that this 'switching' occurs at a frequency linearly proportional to the value $V/D$. Why this is the case (to my mind) is that the time taken for the flow in the free stream (just above the cylindrical surface above the boundray layer) to navigate one side of the curcumfrerence of the cylinder is roughly (of course there is a dependency on the characteristic length scale of the object) the flow crossing time. Remember as the flow hit the bluff leading edge of the cylinder it...

Comment: is slowed right down, it then speeds up as it propagates to the seperation point. You may say that "wait, but is takes time for the vorticies to be created before they are shed". Well, yes, but this too is directly related to the flow velocity (for a constnt Re - for the Re range you have referenced). How _exactly_, well it is complex see [this thesis](http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/1751/1/Schatzman_JC_1981.pdf) for an early but complete analysis of the phenominon. I must note, that your question was specifically reguarding the $V/D$ (_"Without using dimensional analysis of course"_)...